# Reduce vertical distance of "above right" to label a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I label a plot using `above right` but with reduced vertical distance? I tried a syntax like `above right= value1 and value2` but this isn't working for me.

For example in the following plot:

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=12]
    \addplot[black] {1} node[pos=0.1, above right]{$y=1$};
    \addplot[black] {2} node[pos=0.1, above right]{$y=2$};
    \addplot[black] {3} node[pos=0.1, above right]{$y=3$ long info};
    \addplot[black] {4} node[pos=0.1, above right]{$y=3$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the font to be smaller, or a little bit shifted downwards?

Comment: Shifted downwards. I didn't think about `yshift` for some reason. Thank you.

Comment: You can put dimensions in to `above right` like `above right= <dimen> and <dimen>`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Did you tried it? For me `\addplot[black] {4} node[pos=0.1, above right=1pt and 1pt]{$y=3$};` isn't working.

Comment: Yes it works, provided you put `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you! I wasn't aware that it only works with the `positioning` library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new style called `mylabel` and shift it a bit vertically (`y`). This way you can just redefine the style, and all labels placed this way will look the same (3 and 4).
With the tikzlibrary `positioning` you can do something like `above right=  and . See plots 5 and 6. Thanks at @HarishKumar for pointing that out.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9,
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
mylabel/.style={above right, yshift=-2pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=12]
     \addplot[black] {1} node[pos=0.1, above right]{$y=1$};
     \addplot[black] {2} node[pos=0.1, above right]{$y=2$ long info};
     \addplot[black] {3} node[pos=0.1, mylabel]{$y=3$ long info};
     \addplot[black] {4} node[pos=0.1, mylabel]{$y=3$};
     \addplot[black] {5} node[pos=0.1, above right=-2pt and 1pt]{$y=5$};
     \addplot[black] {6} node[pos=0.1, above right=-2pt and 8pt]{$y=6$ long info};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```